# Delphi - WM_MOUSEWHEEL double processing

Tags: delphi, winapi, mousewheel

I’ve added a mouse wheel handler to my application’s main window, and it seems to work, but not in the way I’m expecting from the MSDN on line documentation.

According to the MSDN help, the result should be set to zero to indicate that the message has been handled, but if I do this, then the routine is called twice. Setting to a non-zero value (in my case –1) results it is only being called once.

Here is some test code which illustrates the problem:

```
unit Mouse_Wheel_Testing;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Debug: TEdit;
    procedure MouseWheelHandler(var Message: TMessage); override;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Call_Count: integer;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Call_Count := 0;
  Debug.Text := IntToStr(Call_Count);
end;

procedure TForm1.MouseWheelHandler(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inc(Call_Count);
  Debug.Text := IntToStr(Call_Count);
  Message.Result := -1;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Do you have a specific reason not to use the forms existing events: `OnMouseWheel` or `OnMouseWheelDown` and `OnMouseWheelUp`?

Comment: Yes. Based upon my testing, the OnMouseWheel event only fires when a control on the form which supports mouse wheel scrolling has focus. If I could be sure it would always fire, then I'd be happy to use the existing event.

Comment: So, you want to direct all mouse wheel messages to a specific form, even if a component on another form has focus, is that correct? I don't see how overriding `MouseWheelHandler()` will help you there. OTOH, an `OnMessage` handler for a `TApplicationEvents` like this `procedure TForm19.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Msg.message = WM_MOUSEWHEEL then
    Msg.hwnd := Form19.Handle;
end;
` will direct all mousewheel messages to `Form19` (in this case), where you can use `OnMouseWheel()` event.

Comment: Thanks Tom. For some reason the over-ridden MouseWheelhandler fires every time, but the OnMouseWheel does not. I'm not sure why, as I would have thought they would behave in a similar manner. Thanks for the tip regarding the application event handler. That gives me another option if the need arises. I'd still like to know why the OnMouseWheel event doesn't always fire though, and why the result code I'm returning in my handler appears to be contrary to the MSDN documentation. Things that don't behave as per the documentation always make me nervous.

Comment: I'm making progress. I've just found that if there is a component such as a string grid on my form, and this component has focus, then the form's OnMouseWheel event won't fire, even though the overridden MouseWheelHandler will always fire. Interesting.

Comment: You'll likely find the answer here: [What’s with this MSH_MOUSEWHEEL message?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080806-00/?p=21353)

Comment: From looking at VCL code there seems to be the assumption that `Result = 0` is unhandled. E.g.  `if Message.Result = 0 then inherited;`

Comment: You are seeing your message twice in the handler because first the focused control receives it, `TControl` will call `MouseWheelHandler` of its parent form. Then the unhandled message is propagated to the window's parent, your second entry in your handler.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That tallies with my observations. Interesting that in the VCL code 0 = unhandled, whereas in the MSDN documentation, 0 = handled.

Comment: VCL is free to implement its own design within the framework's processing. Additionally MSDN states that controls should return true if they process the message; see remarks in docs.

Answer (score 3):

From the initial question and the following comments there are two parts to this question:

- How is a message indicated as handled?
- Why do the calls to the message handlers seem so incoherent, `MouseWheelHandler` is called twice, `OnMouseWheel` never called depending on Controls on your form?

For the first part, the VCL code assumes that a `Message.Result <> 0` indicates a handled message. In your test you set the `Message.Result` to -1, hence it is handled. As Sertac Akyuz remarks, this might not be what the MSDN defines, but a design decision in the VCL.

For the second part there are two fundamentals. First, the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL`, a system-generated message. Second, the `CM_MOUSEWHEEL`, Delphi's own **C**ontrol **M**essage distributed internally.

- `MouseWheelHandler` handles `WM_MOUSEWHEEL`
- `OnMouseWheel` (and depending on result and wheel delta `OnMouseWheelUp` / `OnMouseWheelDown`) event(s) fired in response to `CM_MOUSEWHEEL`

Scrolling the mouse wheel let's Windows generate a `WM_SCROLLWHEEL` which is received in the `WndProc` of the focused windowed control. This might be the `TForm` in this case, most likely the `TEdit`, as only focusable control. This message will be dispatched to the handler `MouseWheelHandler`. `TControl.MouseWheelHandler` will try to find the ParentForm it is located in and call the `TForm.MouseWheelHandler`, **first entry to your procedure**. Here - normally - Delphi will `Perform` a `CM_MOUSEWHEEL` on the Form's focused control. Your overridden procedure however, **does not call `inherited` and disables this**. If the message is still unhandled it will be propagated upwards the Parent chain, the Form's `MouseWheelHandler` is called a second time, **second entry to your procedure**.

If `CM_MOUSEWHEEL` messages get generated, they get dispatched to `TControl.CMMouseWheel`. Here, depending on the result of `DoMouseWheel` function either the `CM_MOUSEWHEEL` result is set to 1 or there is a `Parent` control the same message is performed on the `Parent`.
`TStringGrid` e.g. will handle MouseWheel events. The `CM_MOUSEWHEEL`will not be passed to the parent, no scroll wheel events for your form.